# ¿Cómo defino una expresión regular para una serie de fechas con hora separadas por "|"?

Tags: javascript, regex

Necesito que el siguiente *string* haga el match solo si esta de la siguiente manera:

```
const string = '2021-02-16 09:13:19 | 2021-02-16 09:13:00 | 2021-02-23 09:13:00 | 2021-02-22 09:13:00 | 2021-02-20 09:13:00 | 2021-02-23 09:13:00 | 2021-02-20 09:13:00 | 2021-02-26 09:13:00, 2021-02-26 09:13:0';
```

Ocupo que el separador de las fechas sea solo (espacio)|(espacio) y no otros símbolos como ,`.$`, etc. o bien que después del | no haya nada `""`.

Intente algo como esto:

```
const regExp = /\d\d\d\d\-\d\d\-\d\d \d\d\:\d\d\:\d\d( \| |)/g;`
```

Pero no funcionó.

Comment: Las últimas 2 fechas tienen un formato distinto `2021-02-26 09:13:00, 2021-02-26 09:13:0`, están separadas por coma (`,`) y los segundos de hora en la última le falta un dígito. ¿Esto es correcto o es un error?

Comment: Es correcto, la expresion regular deberia debolverme falso dado que no se esta cumpliendo con el criterio del separador  ' | ' o bien, el string no esta escrito correctamente. Lo que quiero hacer, es obligar al usuario a escribir exactamente con el mismo formato.

Comment: ¿Necesitas validar que el formato de la fecha y hora sean válidos? ejemplo: mes `13` , hora `25`, minutos `65`, etc. falle

Comment: No, Por ejemplo: El siguiente string seria correcto, la regExp deveria devolver true.
`var string = '2021-02-16 09:13:19 | 2021-02-16 09:13:00 | 2021-02-23 09:13:00 | 2021-02-22 09:13:00 | 2021-02-20 09:13:00 | 2021-02-23 09:13:00 | 2021-02-20 09:13:00 | 2021-02-26 09:13:00'`
Esto seria incorrecto:
`var string = '2021-02-16 09:13:00 | 2021-02-23 09:13:00 | 2021-02-22 09:13:00 | 2021-02-20 09:13:00 | 2021-02-23 09:13:00 . 2021-02-20 09:13:00 , 202A-02-26 09:13:0'`

Dado que ese string va estar cambiando, y voy a estar agregando fechas ocupo que sigan el mismo formato siempre.

Comment: Por ejemplo: `2021-82-96 79:83:99` no te interesa validarlo?

Comment: Ahora que lo pienso, tambien seria bueno,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Las expresiones regulares pueden ser caras (computacionalmente), si tienes una cadena de texto larga.

Mi sugerencia es que uses el método [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/split) de las cadenas de texto, para dividir las fechas por el separador. Y luego la expresión regular puede ser bastante más sencilla, en otras respuestas tienes algunos ejemplos, pero algo así sería sencillo: `/^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}$/`

Una vez más, para validar las fechas, puedes hacerlo con una expresión regular [como sugiere Marcos en su respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/428732/111983). Otra opción es hacerlo creando un objeto [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Date), o con [`Date.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Date/parse) (devuelve `NaN` si la fecha es inválida).

```js
function comprobarFechas(cadenaFechas) {
  const fechas = cadenaFechas.split(' | ');
  const regex = /^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}$/;

  const correcta = fechas.every(fecha => {
    const pasaRegex = regex.test(fecha);
    const esValida = !isNaN(Date.parse(fecha));;

    console.log(`${fecha} ${pasaRegex ? '' : 'no'} pasa la expresión regular, y es ${esValida ? 'valida' : 'invalida'}`);

    return pasaRegex && esValida;
  });

  console.log(`${correcta ? '' : 'in'}correcta: ${cadenaFechas}`);
};

// Correcta.
comprobarFechas('2021-02-16 09:13:19 | 2021-02-16 09:13:00');

// Incorrecta: Mes 13.
comprobarFechas('2021-02-16 09:13:19 | 2021-13-16 09:13:00');

// Incorrecta: Acaba en barra.
comprobarFechas('2021-02-16 09:13:19 | 2021-02-16 09:13:00 | ');

// Incorrecta: 28 horas.
comprobarFechas('2021-02-16 28:13:19 | 2021-02-16 09:13:00');

// Incorrecta: Separación en comas.
comprobarFechas('2021-02-16 28:13:19 , 2021-02-16 09:13:00');

// Incorrecta: Falta un espacio.
comprobarFechas('2021-02-16 28:13:19 |2021-02-16 09:13:00');
```

Una clara ventaja de esta aproximación es que la expresión regular es más sencilla de leer. El uso de `split()` también es fácil de leer, y la validación de la fecha ya viene hecha y no tienes que preocuparte.

Una desventaja, precisamente de la validación, es que acepta cualquier mes con 31 días. Por ejemplo, `new Date(Date.parse('2021-02-31'))` es válido. Lo bueno es que al menos devuelve 3 de marzo de 2021.

Comment: Hola Adrian, al final termine haciendo lo parecido a lo que mencionas, les agradezco mucha la ayuda a todos, saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Hacerlo en una única expresión regular es complejo, porque tienes un timestamp al final pero opcionalmente tienes varios antes:

```
(?:\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2} \| )*\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}$
```

Que explicada es:

```
^(?:\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2} \| )* ---> Timestamp con " | " al final
                                                  repetido de 0 a N veces
Timestamp al final de la línea --->          \d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}$
```

```js
const regex = /(?:\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2} \| )*\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}$/;
const string = '2021-02-16 09:13:19 | 2021-02-16 09:13:00 | 2021-02-23 09:13:00 | 2021-02-22 09:13:00 | 2021-02-20 09:13:00 | 2021-02-23 09:13:00 | 2021-02-20 09:13:00 | 2021-02-26 09:13:00, 2021-02-26 09:13:0';
const string2 = '2021-02-16 09:13:19 | 2021-02-16 09:13:00 | 2021-02-23 09:13:00 | 2021-02-22 09:13:00 | 2021-02-20 09:13:00 | 2021-02-23 09:13:00 | 2021-02-20 09:13:00 | 2021-02-26 09:13:00 | 2021-02-26 09:13:00';


console.log(regex.test(string));
console.log(regex.test(string2));
```

Pero esto sólo valida el formato, se podría complicar mucho más si quisieras comprobar que

- el mes está entre 00 y 12,
- el día está entre 01 y 30, 31, 28 o 29, según el mes
- que la hora está entre 00 y 24
- etc

Quizá te convenga más hacer un split por `|` y luego hacer un parse de la fecha, usando alguna librería para formatear, como puede ser [Luxor](https://moment.github.io/luxon/docs/manual/parsing.html):

```js
const string = '2021-02-16 09:13:19 | 2021-02-16 09:13:00 | 2021-02-23 09:13:00 | 2021-02-22 09:13:00 | 2021-02-20 09:13:00 | 2021-02-23 09:13:00 | 2021-02-20 09:13:00 | 2021-02-26 09:13:00, 2021-02-26 09:13:0';


const dates = string.split(" | ");

dates.forEach(date => {
  const result = luxon.DateTime.fromSQL(date);
  if (result.isValid) { 
    console.log('formateado: ',result);
  } else {
    console.log('Error:',date,result.invalidReason);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/luxon@1.26.0/build/global/luxon.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Para validar el formato de la fecha hora podemos hacerlo así:

- Para el año: `\d{4}`
- Para el mes: `(0[1-9]|1[0-2])`
- Para el día: `(0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[0-1])`
- Para la hora: `([01]\d|2[0-3])`
- Para los minutos: `[0-5]\d`
- Para lo segundos: `[0-5]\d`

Al unir todo esto, nos quedaría:

```
\d{4}-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[0-1]) ([01]\d|2[0-3]):[0-5]\d:[0-5]\d
```

Para validar que puede haber mas de una fecha separada por `|`, podríamos agregar

```
( \| (\d{4}-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[0-1]) ([01]\d|2[0-3]):[0-5]\d:[0-5]\d)?)*
```

Resultando en:

```
/^\d{4}-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[0-1]) ([01]\d|2[0-3]):[0-5]\d:[0-5]\d( \| \d{4}-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[0-1]) ([01]\d|2[0-3]):[0-5]\d:[0-5]\d)*$/
```

#### Ejemplo:

```js
const regExp = /^\d{4}-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[0-1]) ([01]\d|2[0-3]):[0-5]\d:[0-5]\d( \| (\d{4}-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[0-1]) ([01]\d|2[0-3]):[0-5]\d:[0-5]\d)?)*$/;

console.log(regExp.test('2021-02-16 09:13:19'));
console.log(regExp.test('2021-02-16 09:13:19 | 2021-02-16 09:13:19'));
console.log(regExp.test('2021-02-16 09:13:19 | 2021-02-16 09:13:19 | '));
console.log(regExp.test('2021-02-16 09:13:19 | 2021-02-16 09:13:00 | 2021-02-23 09:13:00 | 2021-02-22 09:13:00 | 2021-02-20 09:13:00 | 2021-02-23 09:13:00 | 2021-02-20 09:13:00 | 2021-02-26 09:13:00, 2021-02-26 09:13:0'));
```